# Where to manage admin-only MS Graph permissions for app registered through Application Registration Portal

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have created a native application in the Application Registration Portal at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

I have configured an Xcode project based on the MSAL framework for iOS, and am able to consume data from MS Graph when only the user's consent is required (like User.ReadBasic.All)

However, if I want to access the User.Read.All scope, it doesn't work. I am met with the requirement for an admin to give access (as expected), but my administrator is not able to find the place to give the necessary permissions.

Logging in with administrator credentials when prompted for them in the webview 'grant access' screen (see screenshot below) doesn't work (redirects back to the same screen again, seemingly not accepting the admin credentials as admin credentials).

[image]

We are not sure whether that is the way to grant the application the permissions anyway, since the documentation is not explicit about how the admin can grant the necessary permissions.

We cannot find the place in Azure AD where the admin permission can be granted.

There is a lot of documentation about how to use the MSAL framework, but there seems to be that step missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the microsoft graph permissions that your app requires in the application registration portal, you could manually request admin consent by redirecting to admin consent endpoint in browser:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

Please click here for more detail about [admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) .

For iOS the redirect URL needs to match the URL scheme registered in the app, which is msal{client-id}://auth if you used guided setup when creating the app on apps.dev.microsoft.com. It only works if you put the admin consent endpoint above into the browser on the phone where the app is installed, since otherwise there is nothing to redirect to.

Comment: I misread your answer, didn't realise that we should manually put it into the browser. Will try asap and get back